# how to create a frequency histogram with predefined non-uniform intervals?

Tags: r

How can I make a histogram in RStudio with the frequency on the y-axis and on the x-axis pre-defined non-uniform intervals, for example: 0-50, 50-150, 150-500, 500-2000.

I have hypothetical data, as I would not like to share my original data.

```
data <- c(1,1.2,40,1000,36.66,400.55,100,99,2,1500,333.45,25,125.66,141,5,87,123.2,61,93,85,40,205,208.9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the breaks you want with the `breaks` argument in the `hist` function.

```
hist(data, breaks=c(0, 50, 150, 500, 2000), freq=TRUE)
```

[image]

### Update

If you want even bar widths you need to put your data into a categorical format rather than continuous. You could achieve this by doing the following.

```
# Cut your data into categories using your breaks
data <- cut(data, 
            breaks=c(0, 50, 150, 500, 2000),
            labels=c('0-50', '50-150', '150-500', '500-2000'))
# Make a data table (i.e. a frequency count)
data <- table(data)
# Plot with `barplot`
barplot(data)
```

[image]

Comment: but why did the bar vary in size?

Comment: This is because your data is continuous and not categorical. I'll update my answer to show what to do if you want even bar sizes.