# how to add labels above the bar of "barplot" graphics?

Tags: r

I asked a question before, but now I would like to know how do I put the labels above the bars.

post old: [how to create a frequency histogram with predefined non-uniform intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65056651/how-to-create-a-frequency-histogram-with-predefined-non-uniform-intervals)

```
dataframe <- c (1,1.2,40,1000,36.66,400.55,100,99,2,1500,333.45,25,125.66,141,5,87,123.2,61,93,85,40,205,208.9)
```

Upatdate

Update

Following the guidance of the colleague I am updating the question.

I have a data base and I would like to calculate the frequency that a given value of that base appears within a pre-defined range, for example: 0-50, 50-150, 150-500, 500-2000.

in the post([how to create a frequency histogram with predefined non-uniform intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65056651/how-to-create-a-frequency-histogram-with-predefined-non-uniform-intervals)) I managed to do this, but I don't know how to add the labels above the bars. I Tried:

`barplort (data, labels = labels)`, but it didn't work.

I used barplot because the post recommended me, but if it is possible to do it using ggplot, it would be good too.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317948/how-to-label-histogram-bars-with-data-values-or-percents-in-r) help?

Comment: Please don't tag `rstudio` for the posts which have nothing to do with R Studio IDE.

Comment: If the question @eipi10 linked doesn't help, please add more details and a reproducible example of your visualisation (so this question is self-contained)

Comment: @stragu i edited issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [the answer to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056672/1494531), here is one way to add a `text()` element to your Base R plot, that serves as a label for each one of your bars (assuming you want to double-up the information that is already on the x axis).

```r
data <- c(1,1.2,40,1000,36.66,400.55,100,99,2,1500,333.45,25,125.66,141,5,87,123.2,61,93,85,40,205,208.9)
# Cut your data into categories using your breaks
data <- cut(data, 
            breaks = c(0, 50, 150, 500, 2000),
            labels = c('0-50', '50-150', '150-500', '500-2000'))
# Make a data table (i.e. a frequency count)
data <- table(data)
# Plot with `barplot`, making enough space for the labels
p <- barplot(data, ylim = c(0, max(data) + 1))
# Add the labels with some offset to be above the bar
text(x = p, y = data + 0.5, labels = names(data))
```

[image]

If it is the y values that you are after, you can change what you pass to the `labels` argument:

```r
p <- barplot(data, ylim = c(0, max(data) + 1))
text(x = p, y = data + 0.5, labels = data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>